# How to load JSON values into tableview array using objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

How to load `jsonDictionary[@"response"][obj][@"color"]` into table view array. Here below sample code I am using but every time I am getting bad exception at `return [tableviewArray count];`. Please give some solution for my problem.

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

// get keys from response dictionary
NSMutableArray * key = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[jsonDictionary[@"response"] allKeys]];

// sort as asending order
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" ascending: YES];
key =  (NSMutableArray *)[key sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];

// access inner data from dictonary
for (NSString * obj in key) {

    // Here below values I want to apply for tableview array
    NSLog(@"%@",jsonDictionary[@"response"][obj][@"color"]);
    NSArray *tableviewArray = [jsonDictionary[@"response"][obj][@"color"]]; 
}
```

I am getting bad exception on below tableview method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableviewArray count]; // Here am getting bad exception
}
```

My JSON:

```
{
    response: {
        RED: {
            Color: "red",
            color_id: "01"},
        GREEN: {
            Color: "green",
            color_id: "02"}
    },
    Colorcode: {},
    totalcolor: "122"
}
```

Comment: you have already asked this question yesterday, update it and then get an answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31586794/how-to-get-the-values-from-nested-json-objective-c

Comment: No its differnt kind of question. There I asked how to get the values from JSON. Here I am asking how to load into tableview @developer

Comment: What is the exception?  It seems that you are creating `tableviewArray` as a local variable inside the loop.  This will be released once the loop ends.  You need to store the results into a property or iVar.  Also your loop makes no sense, because only the last array will be assigned to `tableviewArray` - the earlier array references will be overwritten

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7966c8b0
2015-07-24 10:39:49.477 Mvp_Discern[1125:19054] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7966c8b0'

Comment: Anyone give me clear code for my problem.I know I decelared array locally. It's for clarification.

Comment: will u please post ur response ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare colorArray in .h file & alloc init it in viewDidLoad method.
as

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
colorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

add color array as below:-

```
  NSMutableArray 
 for (NSString * obj in key) {

 // Here below values I want to apply for tableview array
 NSLog(@"%@",jsonDictionary[@"response"][obj][@"color"]);

[colorArray addObject:dict[@"response"][obj][@"Color"]]; // here I am applying array
}
```

then you can access colorArray in tableview delegate method.

Comment: It's not good. tableviewArray1 = [jsonDictionary[@"response"][obj][@"color"]]; // Incompatabile pointer array. Making bad exception. @pooja

Comment: check now .I have made changes.

Comment: [jsonDictionary[@"response"][obj][@"color"]]; // expected identifier error. moreover check all close brackets  for NSArray and bad eception facing at tableviewArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: tableviewArray1]; @pooja

Comment: No. Making bad exception. reason: '-[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78735380' @poojathorat

Comment: may be you are assigning NSNumber to NSString in cellforRowatIndexpath delegate method of tableview

Comment: Nope. valuelbl.text = [tableviewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Now am getting -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x796e5580'

Comment: will u please NSlog your  tableviewArray contents

Comment: Yes I did. I can get values from tableviewArray1 but tableviewArray I cant get anything only above bad exceptions.@pooja

Comment: check updated code now.Problem may be due to the double allocating tableviewArray

Comment: Nope. globally I cant get any values...Tableview shwoing empty because of null.@pooja

Comment: nslog colorArray u will get colors there.

Comment: I am asking outside how can I get? Its not possible. How to load that values into tableview. within loop I can get all values. what about outside loop.@pooja

Answer (score 0):

I think you get exception because you have not initialized it when this view controller get loaded. Because, it will load the `UITableView` as well and you should at least return 0 in order to let it display a empty table view after finishing loading it. For you case, it does not even return 0 because your `tableviewArray` is nil. So, you should call reload then after finishing loading it.